# Retiring Badges

Tags: discussion, badges

I was looking at the list of badges, and noticed a few were retired, and then I noticed a couple that appear impossible to get but are not.

The 'Precognitive' and 'Beta' badges are not retired, but I am assuming that the proposal and beta periods have long since passed by, making it impossible to get them.

should they be listed as retired?

Comment: Badges for acknowledged, aging experts who are slowly becoming less active _should_ be honored with **Retiring** badges. How would it work? Some function of age, reputation, and last year's rep, I think, along with some suitable constants. BTW, is there a flag for "good answer, to a different question"?

Comment: @martin f Yes, there is such a flag and several people activated it to point out your reply fits the bill :-).  That's why I converted it to a comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Badges are an SE-wide feature.  Although it is no longer possible for anyone here on GIS to earn a Precognitive or Beta badge, it continues to be possible to earn them on emerging sites.  Therefore they cannot be retired.